pgAdmin not opening on macOS High Sierra
Hello I'm currently trying to expand my skill set and learn SQL. When trying to open pgAdmin I don't get an error code nor any other messages the application simply won't open in chrome/safari. I've downloaded multiple versions of both pgadmin and postgresql  and still got the same result. What can I do to fix this issue?
After I downloaded versions pgAdmin (6.21) and postgresql (10.23) on my macOS High Sierra (version: 10.13.6). As well as downloading a dvdrental file (provided to me by my course teacher) and after restarting my computer and trying to open pgadmin nothing happens.

Go to youtube and find possible solution.
There are no such issue in postgresql.
https://github.com/porsager/postgres/issues
So, issue is happening in your end. Goto youtube and fixed the issue

Reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fy-42clnbmc
Don't post any question like this.

Slightly offtopic: You are aware PostgreSQL version 10 is EOL since 2022? Just download https://postgresapp.com to get a wide range of supported versions.
